# AppSettings Deserialize to an unknown or dynamic class

Tags: json, asp.net-core, dynamic, appsettings

I'm trying to set up a series of complex app settings in a separate settings.json file - I won't go into detail as to why...

So I have a JSON file which looks like this:

```
{
  "Website": {
    "Name": "Website Name",
    "api_key": "----------",
    "domain": "-----------"
  },
  "Pages": {
    "Index": {
      "Name": "Index",
      "Widgets": {
        "BestSellers": {
          "Name": "BestSellers",
          "Type": "ProductCollection", 
          "Data": {
            "Limit": "8",
            "Sort": {
              "SortType": 3
            },
            "GetFullProducts": true,
            "GroupVariations": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The first section "Website" simply fetches string settings, all working fine.

The section section "Pages" is more complicated. I have classes that look like this:

```
public class PageSettings
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<String, Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
    public class Widget
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<String, object> Data { get; set; }  // THIS IS THE PROPERTY THIS QUESTION IS ABOUT
    }
}
```

I use this code to deserialise the above:

```
IConfigurationSection pagessection = root.GetSection("Pages");

if (pagessection.Exists())   
{ 
    _Pages = new Dictionary<String, PageSettings>();
    pagessection.Bind(_Pages); 
}
```

With the JSON File exactly as above, this will fail. For some reason, the nested Object `Sort` in the `Data` property cannot be deserialised as `Object`:

```
"Sort": {
    "SortType": 3
}
```

If I take the above nested object out then all the code so far will work. However, there are use cases where I need that nested object.

I have tried using `ExpandoObject` which is very cool and clever, but because it expects `KeyValuePair`s, it then **only** serialises the nested object in `Data`, ignoring the simple properties Limit, GetFullroduct etc.

**So what I need is a form of `ExpandoObject` which can also be `ExpandoString` or something?!**

**Alternatively**... I need to be able to get the `Data` property from the settings.json file in `String` form and explicitly deserialise it using `JsonConvert.Deserialize` at the point of use, because at that point I can declare the proper class that it needs to be deserialised to, but i can't seem to find a way to get the `IConfigurationSection` code to get the value as a string, rather than a JSON object.

Comment: You can try to make `Data` property as [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)like this `public JObject Data { get; set; }`. Here is [test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2wfY.png).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. From the docs it looks just right, but when I run it, I get this error: `Cannot create instance of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' because it is either abstract or an interface` if I include the nested `Sort` type.

Comment: Which code snippet cause this error?

Comment: Hmmm... well, after further investigation, I think it is deserialising OK, but for some reason when I come to use it that error is thrown. The class `PageSettings` is slightly more complicated than in my original example, being used as singleton class         `private Dictionary<String, PageSettings> _Pages;
        public static Dictionary<String, PageSettings> Pages
        {
             get => Instance._Pages; // ERROR THROWN HERE
        }` the error is thrown when the private_Pages property is set to the public one...

Comment: Ah - I think I have it, I was just missing `{get;set;}` on the `private Dictionary<String, PageSettings> _Pages;` declaration. :D

Comment: Dammit! No, that wasn't the problem, I was testing with the nested `Sort` class missing. It is failing on retrieving the data on the private property.

Comment: Nope - sorry, I am wrong again! Reading further into the error, it is on this line that the error is hit: `pagessection.Bind(_Pages);`

Comment: Yup - I've changed the class around a bit to simplify the constructor, but the error is triggered at `pagessection.Bind(Pages);` which makes me think the deserliazer that is used in Binding is not coping with nested JObjects...

Comment: More completely: `Pages = new Dictionary<String, PageSettings>(); pagessection.Bind(Pages);`

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a solution to this, the nested object breaks everything I have tried.

The helpful comment from @Fei Han has helped a little in highlighting the flexibility of the `JObject` class, so the solution I have come to is this:

1. The complex class has to be stored as an HTML encoded string in the settings.json file:

   "Data": "{"Limit": "8","GetFullProducts":true,"GroupVariations":true, "Sort": {"SortType": 3}}"

it has to be HTMLEncoded because it is the only way I can find to make the ConfigurationBuilder treat it as a string so that I can cast it correctly later.

The corresponding Class for this now has these properties:

```
public string ModelString { get; set; }
public Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject Model
{
    get
    {
        string s = ModelString.HtmlDecode();
        if (s.EmptyStr())
        {
           return new JObject();
        } else {
            return JObject.Parse(s);
        }
    }
}
```

From this I am able to easily cast my Data to the eventually required class using `.ToObject<MyObject>()`

For some reason, this works. I am able to deserialise the string to a `JObject` in this method, but not directly using the `Bind` command on `IConfigurationSection`.

If anyone has any tips on why `Bind` won't do it, that'd be interesting!